# select earliest time in the same day ODOO

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

so, i have attendance of student that have 3 session with different time. if 1 student is absent at 7 am, the next class should automatically set that student to absent. the problem is when teacher in the early class forgot to do attendance and the next class do the attendance first. then the first class absence would follow the second class. it shouldn't be like that because student may leave class after the first class. this is my code.

```
@api.multi
    def get_today_session(self):
        attendance_obj = self.env['event.session.attendance']
        for session in self:
            for att in session.attendance_ids:
                attendance_ids = attendance_obj.search([('student_id', '=', att.student_id.id),('date', '=', att.date),('id', '!=', att.id)], order='hour_from desc')
                print(att.hour_from[0])
                if attendance_ids:
                    attendance_id = attendance_ids[0]
                    att.write({
                            'attendance' : attendance_id.attendance,
                            'late_reason' : attendance_id.late_reason.id,
                            'reason' : attendance_id.reason.id,
                            'to_verify' : attendance_id.to_verify,
                            'action_needed' : attendance_id.action_needed,
                            'remark' : attendance_id.remark,
                        })
```

i think i needed to just add another parameter at the search function but i couldn't found a way to do it.
summary: need a parameter that check if session is the earliest, if not, when the next class attendance is filled up, the first class attendance should not follow the second class attendance. the first class attendance should be all present.

Comment: Instead of searching attendances, you should search earlier sessions. After that you can see if  attendances are filled.

Comment: Hi,i had thought about that to but couldn't find a way to do that. I tried to play with hour_from but still didn't get the result i wanted. Can you tell me what should i do?